# Use PHP function to override default JSON target with Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

We built an API to directly access other social networks APIs using our keys.

I'm trying to build a fuction to access that API.

The default function has been written and is working.

**Question**

- How can I specify a new array to target the json data?

  - This will override the default setting.

---

```
function SocialAPI($handle, $service, $path="") {
    $handle = strtolower($handle);
    $service = strtolower($service);

    $api = file_get_contents("https://api.service.domain.com/v1/Social?handle=$handle&service=$service");

    if($api !== false) {
        $data = json_decode($api, true);

        if($data !== null) {
            if($service === "twitter") {
                return $data['0']['followers_count'];
            }
            if($service === "instagram") {
                if(!empty($path)) {
                    while($id = array_shift($path)) {
                        echo $data[$id];
                    }
                    return $data;
                } else {
                    return $data['user']['followed_by']['count'];
                }
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return "API call failed.";
    }
}

//Test API Function - ** TO BE DELETED **
echo SocialAPI("JohnDoe", "Instagram", "['user']['full_name']");

exit();
```

Comment: You're passing a string and not a array for your third argument. It should be $values = array("user", "full_name"); SocialAPI("JohnDoe", "Instagram",$values);

Comment: @iSZ I've tried this - but I just get an the return value of `ArrayArray`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function array_deref($data, $keys) {
    return empty($keys) ? $data
        : array_deref($data[$keys[0]], array_slice($data, 1))
}

function SocialAPI($handle, $service, $path="") {
    $handle = strtolower($handle);
    $service = strtolower($service);

    $api = file_get_contents("https://api.service.domain.com/v1/Social?handle=$handle&service=$service");
    if ($api === false) {
        return "API call failed.";
    }

    $data = json_decode($api, true);
    if($data !== null) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($service === "twitter") {
        if (empty($path)) $path = ['0','followers_count'];
        return array_deref($data, $path);
    } elseif ($service === "instagram") {
        if (empty($path)) $path = ['user','followed_by'];
        return array_deref($data, $path);
    }
}

//Test API Function - ** TO BE DELETED **
echo SocialAPI("JohnDoe", "Instagram", ['user', 'full_name']);
echo SocialAPI("JohnDoe", "Instagram");

exit();
```

I added a utility function, `array_deref`, to walk the arrays recursively (calls itself to handle each level down).

Comment: Hi, great but I think I've mislead the question (thank you to whoever edited it) basically by default I'd like to access the followers data `$data['user']['followed_by']` however in the future I may want to override this by simply adding to the function `SocialAPI("JohnDoe", "Instagram", ['user', 'full_name'])` this would therefore set the data target to `$data['user']['full_name']`. So instead of accessing `$data['user']['followed_by']['count']` it would access the new data path. I really hope that makes sense - the more I try to resolve this the more I seem to confuse myself.

Comment: The code above does just that.  If you don't specify a `$path` then `empty($path)` is true and `$path` will be set to the default value.  I added a second test to code above.